# Open CV error--Face Recognition on MAC

Tags: opencv

I have a facedetection training code. It gives me some issues and i have no clue why.
 I am using a MAC and seems like there is missing something. Can you please advise what should i do?

Thank you in advance

```
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (!empty()) in detectMultiScale, file /tmp/opencv-20180426-73279-16a912g/opencv-3.4.1/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp, line 1698
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/OpenCV-Python-Series-master/src/faces-train.py", line 36, in <module>
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image_array, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) /tmp/opencv-20180426-73279-16a912g/opencv-3.4.1/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1698: error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale
```

[Finished in 0.421s]

And my code is below.

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import pickle

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
image_dir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "images")

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascades/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

current_id = 0
label_ids = {}
y_labels = []
x_train = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(image_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith("png") or file.endswith("jpg"):
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            label = os.path.basename(root).replace(" ", "-").lower()
            #print(label, path)
            if not label in label_ids:
                label_ids[label] = current_id
                current_id += 1
            id_ = label_ids[label]
            #print(label_ids)
            #y_labels.append(label) # some number
            #x_train.append(path) # verify this image, turn into a NUMPY arrray, GRAY
            pil_image = Image.open(path).convert("L") # grayscale
            size = (550, 550)
            final_image = pil_image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            image_array = np.array(final_image, "uint8")
            #print(image_array)
            faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image_array, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)

            for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                roi = image_array[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                x_train.append(roi)
                y_labels.append(id_)


#print(y_labels)
#print(x_train)

with open("pickles/face-labels.pickle", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(label_ids, f)

recognizer.train(x_train, np.array(y_labels))
recognizer.save("recognizers/face-trainner.yml")
```

Answer (score 1):

The assertion which fails indicates that your cascade is not loaded correctly. You can verify it by calling `face_cascade.empty()` just after the constructor. Please make sure that the path you provided (`'cascades/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml'`) is correct. When it points to a not existing file then there is no exception thrown by the constructor so you can easily miss it without calling `empty()` explicitly.